# How do I setup dotnet Release config build in Visual Studio Code with C# Dev Kit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

I've installed Visual Studio Code and the "C# Dev Kit".  It looks like there are no default way to let people choose Release config build.

Looking through the doc packages, it mentions about tasks.json.  Using the "Task Configure Default Build Task" command, it setup the followings tasks.josn for me:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "dotnet",
            "task": "build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "label": "dotnet: build"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to modify that to do Release config build.  I tried changing it to the followings:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "dotnet",
            "task": "build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "options": {
                "shell": {
                    "executable": "dotnet",
                    "args": [
                        "build",
                        "${workspaceFolder}/TestVSCode.sln",
                        "-c",
                        "Release"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "label": "dotnet: build"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it didn't work because when I do build, I still see this on terminal window:

dotnet build /Users/johnleung/TestVSCode/TestVSCode.sln /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary

Did the "C# Dev Kit" basically fixed it so that it can only build with one specific command?

Can I even create my own task to do my own build command?

Answer (score 0):

The command **".NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug"** produces `tasks.json` which looks like this (I've ommited `publish` and `watch` tasks):

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MySolution.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary;ForceNoAlign"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

The generated file can be used as template for custom `dotnet build` tasks. Add `--configuration=Release` to `args` like this:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "dotnet build debug",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MySolution.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary;ForceNoAlign"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "dotnet build release",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/MySolution.sln",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary;ForceNoAlign",
                "--configuration=Release"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

(Here I've added separate release task and adjusted the labels.)

After that, invoke release build through command pallete: "Tasks: Run Task"/"dotnet build release".

Seems like this topic should be covered in C# Dev Kit docs, but I wasn't able to find it.